# How would I connect power from an emergency security flood light fixture?

Tags: electrical

How would I connect power to the inside of my apt. Building from  the emergency security flood light fixture outside the building?

Comment: First, are you the owner of the building or do you rent? Tapping into common power would not be legal if you are not the owner.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, and hook up? Also please note that security lighting is considered a life safety device, and is covered by some fire and building codes -- notably NFPA 101 and the IBC (international building code) -- and tampering with this equipment may result in prosecution depending on where you live. "Any person(s) found tampering with, willfully undermining, or who negligently fails to maintain fire or life safety equipment may be subject to disciplinary and/or criminal proceedings as outlined in sections 430 and 433 to 436 of the Criminal Code of Canada."